# How do I search for posts by deleted user117644 on math.SE?

Tags: support, search, users

How do I search for posts by user117644? This account has been anonymized but I need to get the posts off it. The answers to similar questions don't apply here. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1579740/how-to-apply-the-binomial-theorem-to-an-bn-a-b) is an example of one of the posts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) comes to the rescue; [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/604494/all-posts-by-user117644) is a list of all 51 posts by this user.

[image]

For reference, here is the query:

```sql
SELECT id AS [Post Link], title, creationdate
    FROM posts WHERE ownerdisplayname = 'user117644'
```